# Methods with two Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I have a problem and want to ask you guys why this code doesn't work and how can I make it work without deleting generics or Methods. I think it's because the method cannot be overloaded since S and T can be the same type, is it correct? But I still have no idea know how to make it work. Thank you!

```
public class GenericFail<S,T> {
    public void doAnything(S sValue){
        System.out.println("Doing anything with S");
    }

    public void doAnything(T sValue){
        System.out.println("Doing anything with T");
    }
}
```

Comment: Type Parameter Naming Conventions: T means  Type , while S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types.. so basically they're both generic types .. that's not overloading

Comment: You can't expect this to work. Which of the methods should be called for `new GenericFail<Integer, Integer>().doAnything(42)`?

Answer (score 5):

The generic type is erased after compilation.
So the two `doAnything()` method have the same signature :

```
doAnything(Object object)
```

since `S` and `T` don't explicitly derive from a more specific type.

To solve the problem : either change the method name to have two distinct names or make `S` and `T` derive from a specific type such as :

```
public class GenericFail<S extends CharSequence, T extends Number> {
```

Comment: you should provide explanation from the beginning!

Comment: thank you!! is CharSequence something like type String ? And is it possible if i only add extends CharSequence for S and just remain T as generic type ?

Comment: You are welcome :)  `CharSequence`  is the interface behind the `String` class. Declaring  one of the two types with a more specific type is indeed enough. After generic erasure, you would have in your example two distinct methods : `doAnything()` with  `Object` as the declared type of the parameter and `doAnything()` with  `CharSequence` as the declared type of the parameter.

Comment: @Yahya I think that it is enough. The OP may dig the subject if he/she wants to.

Answer (score 3):

Because of type erasure the two methods have the same signature, thats not allowed in java. You need to use a workaround.

Your options:

- Change the erasure of the generic types by adding type bounds

  `class GenericFail<S extends Number, T extends Collection<?>>`
- Change the names of the methods, e.g. have `doSAnything` and `doTAnything`

Comment: that doesn't answer his question !

Comment: @Yahya i thought his main question is "how to make it work". I provided two options. Did i miss something?